# Division algebra in Field Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $E$ be a field extension of $F$.

Is any division $E$-algebra necessarily of the form $D\otimes E$, where $D$ is a division $F$-algebra?

I can roughly see that sufficiency is true since any (nonzero) $\sum a_id_i\otimes e_i=c\otimes 1$ for some $c\in D$, which has a multiplicative inverse $c^{-1}\otimes 1$?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true in general. When it is true, we say that the division algebra in question has a descent to $F$ ; it's a difficult problem in general to determine if an algebra has a descent.

As a counter-example : take $E = F(X,Y)$ and put $Q = (X,Y)_E$ the quaternion algebra given by generators $i,j$ satisfying $i^2 = X$, $j^2=Y$ and $ij=-ji$.

Then there is no division algebra $D$ over $F$ such that $Q = D\otimes_F E$. The most natural way to see that would be ramification arguments : $Q$ is ramified at $X$ for instance, but any algebra coming from $F$ is non-ramified everywhere.

A general framework to study this kind of question is Galois cohomology, and particularly Brauer groups. What you are asking is exactly equivalent to the question : if $E/F$ is a field extension, is the restriction map $Br(F)\to Br(E)$ surjective ?

It's true if $E$ and $F$ are local fields for instance (this comes from local class field theory). For global fields it's false, but to see that you need global class field theory, so it's a little tricky (but it shows that one can find a counter-example for any finite extension $E/\mathbb{Q}$).

---

Also, it's not true that if $D$ is a division algebra over $F$ then $D\otimes_F E$ is a division algebra over $E$. Tahe $D = \mathbb{H}$ the Hamilton quternions over $F = \mathbb{R}$, and $E = \mathbb{C}$. Then $D\otimes_F E\simeq M_2(E)$.

This is because $Br(F)\to Br(E)$ is not injective in general.

Comment: Thanks! Is it true in the case of central simple algebras?

Comment: No, the exact same counter-example works, for exactly the same reasons.